# Google OAuth Broken After Heroku Deployment

Tags: express, heroku, google-oauth

My Google OAuth Strategy works perfectly on the client side. However after deploying the project to heroku the OAuth breaks once google attempts to redirect the user back to the specified redirect route. I am getting a Request Timed out error on the '/auth/google/callback/ route which is the route google is sending the user back to after authentication. It is defined in my authRoutes (Screenshot below). I am using PassportJS and Express for my backend. My development keys have been setup correctly as have my Google OAuth routes, the error only occurs upon the redirect from Google. Any help would be much appreciated

Here is my Passport Strategy:

```
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy
const keys = require('../config/keys')
const passport = require('passport')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const User = mongoose.model('users')

// This will store a cookie containing the user ID
// in our session after login is complete
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  // This is called during every request
  // It obtains a user object from the user id we serialized earlier
  // the user object is stored in req.user

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id).then(user => {
      done(null, user);
    });
  });

passport.use (
    new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: keys.googleClientID,
    clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
    callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
    proxy: true
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
         const existingUser = await User.findOne({googleID: profile.id});

        if(!existingUser) {
            const user = await User.create({googleID: profile.id}).save()
            return done(null, user)
        }

        done(null, existingUser)


    })
)
```

Here are my Routes:

```
const passport = require('passport')

module.exports = app => {

// This handles getting authentication details
// (gmail profile) from google
app.get("/auth/google", passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile', 'email']
}))

app.get("/auth/google/callback", passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/surveys')
})

app.get("/api/logout",  (req, res) => {
    // Provided by passport
    req.logout()
    res.redirect('/')
})

app.get("/api/current_user", (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.user)
})
```

}

And my Index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const keys = require('./config/keys');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
require('./models/User');
require('./models/Survey');
require('./services/passport');

mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI);

const app = express();

app.use(
  cookieSession({
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    keys: [keys.cookieKey]
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(passport.initialize());

// This middleware injects a cookie in every request
// to allow us to identify the user
app.use(passport.session());

require('./routes/authRoutes')(app);
require('./routes/billingRoutes')(app);


if(process.env.NODE_ENV == "production"){
  // Express will serve up production assets 
  // like our main.js file or main.css file!
  app.use(express.static('client/build'))

  // Express will serve up the index.html file 
  // if it doesn't recognize the route
  const path = require('path')
  app.get('*', (req, res ) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
  })

}


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

Heroku Error:

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/auth/google/callback?code=4/tgDTZZu8osZZvvMGjX4qaazb46SqNukZU6kNARY7R2enmH21cX6IfkVYSVnVHIoQ_qHaUbLttS_VGiS81KYE3D0&scope=email+profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" host=cryptic-citadel-17268.herokuapp.com request_id=e8eb956d-64e4-4217-b846-91c53953e0a7 fwd="193.203.134.47" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Comment: you will need to expand on "OAuth breaks"

Comment: @pinoyyid I put the error message I am getting at the bottom of the post but I should have put it in the body of the text sorry. I am getting a Request Timed out error on the '/auth/google/callback/ route which is the route google is sending the user back to after authentication. It is defined in my authRoutes

Comment: Please copy your error picture as text in your question. Pictures cannot be indexed or searched by StackOverflow. Your error message indicates that your OAUth Callback URL `/auth/google/callback` did not respond. The status is 503 which means `Service Unavailable` which typically means your code crashed.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the reply. I don't understand how my code is failing, the request to google is working fine so the API key is correct. The code works on the client perfectly so I am at a lost as to why it doesn't work on heroku

Comment: How are you connecting to your database? Are there any environment variables that are different on Heroku Dashboard compared to what you have locally? Do you have a test DB setup?

Comment: @MaviDomates Yes I use all different keys for my production versus my development. I connect to my MongoDB database through mongoose, my MongoDB database is hosted on mLab. My local enviroment uses a different mLab database which also works perfectly so I do not believe it has anything to do with my database setup

Comment: @Cathal how to you know your production can connect to your production DB without any issues? Can you log something in the area : async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
         const existingUser = await User.findOne({googleID: profile.id});

        if(!existingUser) {
            const user = await User.create({googleID: profile.id}).save()
            return done(null, user)
        }

        done(null, existingUser)

Comment: You've mentioned everything is working fine on the local - and you're timing out when you're redirected back. Now when you're redirected back the first thing you're doing is querying your DB

Comment: Also would be good to cover the inside of the async function with try catch in case your await fails.

Comment: @MaviDomates Thanks a million for the help, you were 100% right. When I connect to my mongoURI I left "<" and ">" around my username and password which were meant to be removed. My apologies for wasting your time!

Comment: @Cathal not a bother mate ;) I've added this as an answer now, do you mind accepting as an answer? I'd appreciate the green tick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's how you connect to your DB. You've mentioned that everything is working on your localhost correctly, but your production is giving your errors, please check this bit on prod - your connection error is likely due to production DB key configuration.

```
passport.use (
    new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: keys.googleClientID,
    clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
    callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
    proxy: true
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
         const existingUser = await User.findOne({googleID: profile.id});

        if(!existingUser) {
            const user = await User.create({googleID: profile.id}).save()
            return done(null, user)
        }

        done(null, existingUser)
    })
```